# The collapse menu is not fullwidth

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make design a website using angular. Now the problem is that if I make the collapse-navbar fixed-top then the nav bar is full width but It overlaps the page. Other wise the navbar only covers the content area.

without fixed-top:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH4Xs.png)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-   center ">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" (click)  ="toggler()">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'show': isOpen}">
     <img src="assets/image/coding.png" alt="coding" height="34px" width="34px" class="brand-image">
    <span class="navbar-text">Jamilur Rahman</span>
   <ul class="navbar-nav ">
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active current">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Fixed!!! just needed to make the nav component width 100%

Answer (score 0):

I have copy and paste your code, and works fine [here](http://prntscr.com/nqxwto)

I have guessed that this occurred because you are using Edge, but I have tried here, and [works well too](http://prntscr.com/nqxxi7).

[Look](https://prnt.sc/nqxy03), is the same code.

It may be that you have a style class that is overwriting the bootstrap.